# Loading spatialite tables into GeoPandas GeoDataFrame

Tags: spatialite, geopandas, sqlite

Using information from [here](https://gist.github.com/perrygeo/868135514d2518257bbb), I am trying to load a result of a SQL Python selection into a Geopandas geodataframe. I know pyspatialite is not longer maintained, so have tried using the dbapi2 module from sqlite3. When I run the line:

```
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("SELECT name, Hex(ST_AsBinary(geometry, 27700)) as geom FROM table;", conn, geom_col='geom')
```

I get an error: `no such function: ST_AsBinary`. I thought that that was a basic Python command. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably it is not a Python problem.  It looks like your PostGIS doesn't recognize the ST_AsBinary function.  What version of PostGIS do you use?

Comment: For some reason the spatialite extension has not been loaded successfully and therefore you miss ST_AsBinary and other spatialite functions https://www.gaia-gis.it/stored-procs-win-test/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: I ran `c.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);")` and then it worked